# WooCommerce: updating order

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to run some code everytime after the order is updated using 'woocommerce_update_order' action hook as you can see below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_order', 'update_order' );
```

After some time spent on developing 'update_order' function I realized that it is not called only once as I supposed but it is called multiple times.
So for testing I rewrite 'update order' function as you can see below:

```
function update_order( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $current_count = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_edit_sale_count', true );
    $new_count = 1;
    if( $current_count ) $new_count = $current_count + 1;
    $order->update_meta_data( '_edit_sale_count', $new_count );
    $order->save();
}
```

After updating a single order and checking database, I realized that function 'update_order' is called 1500 times...

So my question is why is this the case? And how I can prevent multiple times execution on single update and force it to run once only?

Thanks